# Read barcode input and store as array for processing

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to read barcodes using a barcode scanner. Each time a label is scanned, it will be read and stored into an array. After it has finished scanning all items, there will be a button to send the array to server to display the item info.

I have done the last part which is the display result of the info using php (refer to this url [angularjs example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp)), but I am stuck at the form using AngularJS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you tried on the scanning side? And some example of how your array data would look?

Comment: The problem you have to overcome are Barcode Readers. Using Javascript this is not possible. However, you have options. You can either use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) or use a different language.

Comment: basically the barcode only read the numeric value from the label. everytime it is scanned, the numeric value will be displayed. example of some value read from the barcode scanner are 188883077887529, 2000002, 2300172

Comment: i make the data more readable at the following link : https://jsfiddle.net/ex1ooxgw/

Comment: so, my idea is,there is a form using angularjs that allow user to scan multiple different barcode, then the scanned value is captured in array... When user finish the scan, it will press a search button.The form will then submit this array for searching. The result will display in a table.

Comment: Your running before you can walk. How are you getting the data from the barcode reader into Javascript?

Comment: basically i already imported all the product info into DB. Now want to build a form to do a search for the list of scanned barcode.